# Tensorflow-Numpy OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to import Keras (using tensorflow), and I am getting this error. I have tried everything I found in the Internet, but still does not work. Please I will appreciate a lot if you help me.

I have read is something with the 32bits and 64bits versions. I have tried everything (downloaded and uninstalled several times everything).

I am pretty sure the problem is with the numpy DLL.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "versiones.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy
  File "C:\Users\Public\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "C:\Users\Marcos Rusinol\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\Marcos Rusinol\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\Public\ANACONDA\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!

I just download a 64 NUMPY wheel and installed it.